# Vue scoped slot child not rendering slot content

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I think I've stumbled over something really strange. I have a `Menu` component which has two ways of managing visibility of a dropdown `div`:

1. Internally using local state;
2. Using `v-model` to keep track on the parent component.

I also have a child component called `MenuItem`. This `MenuItem` (one or more) is to be passed into the `Menu` default slot. The `MenuItem` has a slot of its own, for an icon.

The `Menu` also has a slot for the "activator", an element which toggles the menu visibility. This can be a regular slot, or a scoped slot.

If the visibility of the menu is handled through the scoped slot:

```
<Menu>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <button v-on="on" type="button">Click me</button>
  </template>
</Menu>
```

Then the icon for `MenuItem` will render the first time the menu is visible, but subsequent changes to visibility won't render the icon. The icon slot is optional, so I am checking for it's presences using `this.$slots['icon-left']`, and after the first render this is `undefined`.

However, if I manage the visibility on the parent component using `v-model`, this behaviour is not present.

```
<Menu v-model="isMenuVisible">
  <template v-slot:activator>
    <button @click="isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible" type="button">Click me</button>
  </template>
</Menu>
```

I am using `v-if` for toggling the visibility of the dropdown menu. This behaviour is not present if I use `v-show`. This behaviour is also not present if I do not check for the existence of `this.$slots['icon-left']`.

[I have a full demo of the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cray-p9hh5).

Basically I am very confused as to why this is happening, and I don't even know what to Google.

Comment: I've just discovered that for some reason it's being added to `this.$scopedSlots`... This doesn't make any sense, why is it being added as a scoped slot, when it isn't. It's the child of a scoped slot.

Comment: Well, to answer your comment at least, via [the Vue API docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-scopedSlots), as of Vue 2.6.0, "All `$slots` are now also exposed on `$scopedSlots` as functions," streamlining slot access.

Comment: [Here is an issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11084) on GitHub that outlines this exact issue, though I didn't realise that Vue had done that! Basically after the component is re-rendered, the slot is being registered as a scoped slot, which just sounds broken